# ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION Using a url instead of ip with hosts file

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead, hosts

I'm trying to use laravel homestead and redirect "homestead.dev" to "192.168.10.10". I can see the website using the IP but not "homestead.dev".

I get this error:

```
ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION
```

Pinging homestead.dev responds with 127.0.53.53.
I can access the website with this also: http://127.0.53.53:8000/.

My homestead.yaml:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/myApp/public

databases:
    - myApp

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

hosts file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
192.168.10.10   homestead.dev
```

Comment: If I use `192.168.10.10   myapp.local`
in hosts, I get this error:
`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved it. Problem was with hosts file. This post helped me fix it: https://serverfault.com/a/452269.

When changing hosts file, instead of copying and replacing, I moved and replaced it, and so the permissions got changed.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like name collision, try to use different name, for example `myapp.dev`

Also, you you can try to add this to your `hosts` file:

```
127.0.53.53  homestead.dev
```

Then use `homestead.dev:8000` in your browser.

Also try to reboot PC after that.

Comment: Tried everything u mentioned and still the same error :/

Comment: If I use 
    `192.168.10.10   myapp.local`
in hosts, I get this error:
`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: Did you reboot you computer after that? Are you sure you saved changes in hosts file? On some Windows versions sometimes it looks like you saved a hosts file, but when you reopen the file, you can see changes were not saved. When you use 192.168.10.10 in a browser, do you see Laravel starting page?

Comment: Yes I see the starting page using 192.168.10.10. Also I'm sure it is changed, I turned off antivirus to change it and also reopened file.

Comment: Ok, are you using `myapp.local` or `myapp.local:8000`?

Comment: Both give same error. It worked for me before with another app, now when I added a new project to "Code" folder, changed homestead.yaml and hosts file, it doesn't work. Maybe it has something to do with this.